# Would it be possible to sandbox apps with SELinux?

Tags: security, selinux, sandboxing

Many apps require too much permissions that they do not need to function

Most apps needs internet connection to talk to some API (let's say updates checking or notifications.. etc) and need to access SD Card (for buffering/caching). But if we grant them this they can take all of my data.

It would be great if the OS is structured in a way so that we can grant apps access only to specific directories that only belong to it (think of browser cache, youtube buffer ...) and when the user promptly and consciously want to pass files (eg. upload file throw a web browser) they get staged/promoted/linked to that area accessible by the app.

till that happens, we have SELinux in many android phones can we use it to sandbox apps (the idea is there since 2009 see http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/28545.html)

here is the question: can we define a policy that says (if yes how)

- those apps are not allowed to access my gallery directory (DCIM)
- those apps are allowed to access my gallery but are not allowed to use network connection

in desktop Linux it was successfully applied (here it was applied on firefox http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/31146.html)

Comment: AFAIK, SELinux requires a file system that supports extended attributes, and in most devices, SD card are formatted as FAT which cannot store extended attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Android already has this kind of sandboxing of apps. Each app gets its own data directory (and optionally another on the SD card), and only that app can read that directory. Apps can't read other apps' directories directly.

When an app (such as the gallery) wants to make its content available to other apps, they can offer an interface for the other apps to use. In fact, there are two kinds of interfaces apps can offer.

The first is via the *intent* mechanism. This is used when you get (for example) a "Choose image from" dialog, with different apps to choose. The *intent* mechanism allows the app that owns the image to grant the calling app **temporary** access to **only** the image(s) you choose this way.

The second mechanism is for the app to act as a *content provider*. The app then acts like a server, allowing other apps to browse and find content, and access it directly without your interaction. When an app acts this way, it's up to the app that owns the content to choose what security mechanism to use. The app might require that the calling app have a particular *permission* (even a new permission specially created for this purpose). For example, access to contacts is provided this way. Only the built-in *contacts provider* app has direct access to the contacts database. It also acts as a content provider, to allow other apps access, but only if they have the appropriate permission (such as "read my contacts").

So, as you can see, the mechanism you describe - to sandbox apps, and to pass files from one app to another only through the user's choice - already exists in Android. It's way ahead of desktop operating systems in this respect. It's up to apps to use these mechanisms to control the content they own - and there's always going to be a trade-off between granularity of control (using lots of permissions) and making things easier for the user to understand (using fewer permissions).

Comment: But that doesn't work for the parts the OP explicitly named: *those apps are not allowed to access my gallery directory (DCIM)*: this is located on the SDCard, where no "ownership" applies, and *are not allowed to use network connection*: there's no (native) way to accomplish that. Which means, you'll have to trust the apps – or root your device and use LBE/PDroid/XPrivacy/...

Comment: @Fuzzy: That's because the camera folder is decidedly a shared folder. If you don't want this, you'll need to find a camera app that stores its images in the internal private storage or encrypts the images while in external storage.

Comment: as I stated in the question many apps require both "full access to SD" and "full internet access" upon installation. We can only accept or else it won't be installed. It's not opensource to change it. so the only option is to sandbox it

Comment: @fuzzy can you tell me more about LBE,PDroid,XPrivacy

Answer (score -2):

Yes' there is but some apps crashes when they see that they are throttled. Xprivacy module for xposed framework and also app settings. Search and you will find threads at xda pages.